# Ajuda com codigo Pdo para mysqli

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

```
Code ok !
```

-:PDO:- codicgo correto funcionando

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

$response = array();

if ($_POST['delete']) {

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $pid = intval($_POST['delete']);
    $query = "DELETE FROM tbl_products WHERE product_id=:pid";
    $stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->execute(array(':pid'=>$pid));

    if ($stmt) {
        $response['status']  = 'success';
        $response['message'] = 'Product Deleted Successfully ...';
    } else {
        $response['status']  = 'error';
        $response['message'] = 'Unable to delete product ...';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Code com bug nao funciona

```
   header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

 $response = array();

if ($_POST['delete']) { 
    require_once 'dbconfig2.php';
$pid = intval($_POST['delete']);// return form js 

$query = "DELETE FROM tbl_products WHERE product_id=:pid";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$resArr = array(); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) { 
$rs= (array(':pid'=>$pid));

}  
if ($rs) {
        $response['status']  = 'success';
        $response['message'] = 'Product Deleted Successfully ...';
    } else {
        $response['status']  = 'error';
        $response['message'] = 'Unable to delete product ...';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Mudar de PDO para MySQL é uma ótima iniciativa, só que a metodologia muda um pouco. Uma das coisa que precisa fazer é trocar o placeholder `:pid` por `?`, e em vez de `mysqli_query`, precisa de um `mysql_prepare` e um "bind" para associar o `?` ao `$pid`. Uma lidinha no próprio manual do PHP vai ter uma série de explicações e exemplos. Como ficou ampla demais da forma que você postou (vários problemas no código em vez de um problema específico) vou tentar localizar um link do site que possa ajudar.

Comment: Caso o exemplo do post linkado não seja suficiente para você adaptar para o seu caso, queira [edit] a postagem explicando em qual parte do código exatamente está com dúvida.

Comment: Tem um [material](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection) também que eu usei no começo (ao aprender PDO) e me ajudou bastante. Quem sabe te ajude também. Observação: é em inglês.